# How to render a UINavigationController instance in react native using react-navigation and react-native-screens?

Tags: react-native, uinavigationcontroller, react-navigation, react-native-screens

I have a setup where I have bottom navigator created via `createBottomTabNavigator`, and each tab rendering a native stack navigator created via `createNativeStackNavigator`. Now I'm trying to merge another app in written in Swift UIkit.
That app uses `UITabBarController` to render tabs created via `UINavigationController`.
Is it possible, either at tab level or screen level to get those screens to render in React Native?

I tried exposing the `UINavigationController` stack via the `NativeModules` interface, but I'm not sure how to plug that into the JS bottom navigator.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't help with the code, but it needs to be UI component, not a module. Then you'd create a custom navigator with it.

Comment: @satya164 do you mean I can only export RCTViewManager instance and not UINavigationController instance?